# Fix column headers while scrolling horizontally

Tags: html, css, angular

I am trying to fix the column headers so that I can scroll horizontally and yet see the headers. I have tried the following but doesn't seem to work. If you see in the screenshots If I move the screen up or down, the headers dont seem to stay in one place and there is improper overlap. The first td is always hidden behind the th.

screenshot 1[image]

screenshot 2
[image]

```
   th:first-child {
        position: fixed;

    } 

        th {
            position: fixed;
        }
.fixed-side {
    border:1px solid #000;
    background:#eee;
    visibility:visible;
}
```

CSS

```
<style>
    th,
    td {
        padding: 7px;
        min-width: 300px;
        max-width: 300px;
    }

    /* th:first-child {
    position: fixed;

} */


    th {
        position: fixed;
    }

    .fundClassesTable {

        table-layout: fixed;
    }


    .cellbgcolor {
        color: transparent;
    }

    .btn {}

    .tableItem {
        text-align: left;
        border-left: solid 1px lightgrey;
        border-top: solid 1px lightgrey;
        border-right: solid 1px lightgrey;
        border-bottom: solid 1px lightgrey;

    }

    .rowItem:hover {
        background-color: #f5f7f7;
    }


    label {
        margin-left: 0.5rem;
        vertical-align: middle
    }


    .panel-heading {
        color: black;
        border-color: #ddd;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding-top: 5px !important;
        padding-bottom: 5px !important;
    }

    .panel-heading .left-label {
        display: inline-block;
        padding-top: 5px !important;

    }

    .scrollClass {
        overflow-x: scroll;
        display: grid;

    }

    .panel-heading label {
        margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    }

    #FundClass tr:hover {
        background-color: #ECF0F1;
    }

    .headcol {
        position: absolute;
        min-width: 300px;
        max-width: 300px;
        width: 5em;
        left: 0;
        top: auto;
        border-top-width: 1px;
        /*only relevant for first row*/
        margin-top: -1px;
        /*compensate for top border*/
    }

    .headcol:before {
        content: 'Row ';
    }

    .collapsed {
    color: #d6630a;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.expanded {
    color: #d6630a;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;

}

.fixed-side {
    border:1px solid #000;
    background:#eee;
    visibility:visible;
}

</style>
```

HTML

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header panel-heading">
        <span class="left-label" style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; ">Fund Classes</span>

        <a class="pull-right" [ngClass]="{'collapsed': !isExpanded, 'expanded': isExpanded }" data-toggle="collapse"
            href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="expand()" role="button" [attr.aria-expanded]="isExpanded"
            aria-controls="fundClass"> {{ isExpanded ? '-' : '+' }}
        </a>

        <div *ngIf="CanEdit" class="pull-right"
            style="padding-right:10px; display: inline-block; vertical-align:middle">
            <button style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle" class="btn btn-default pull-right"
                (click)="openFundClassModal()"> <i data-bind="visible: true" class="fa fa-plus-square"></i> Add
                Class</button>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right" style="padding-right:10px; display: inline-block; vertical-align:middle">
            <label style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle" class="btn btn-primary"
                [ngClass]="{'btn-primary': InvestedOnly, 'btn-default': !InvestedOnly }"><input type="checkbox"
                    (click)="isInvestedSelected($event)" checked="checked" [(ngModel)]="InvestedOnly" class="hidden"
                    for="chkInvested" />Invested Only</label>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div *ngIf="!FundClasses || !FundClasses.FundDetailsViewModel" style="padding-top:10px">
        <div class="alert alert-warning" style="text-align:center" role="alert">
            Loading... Please Wait
        </div>
    </div>
    <div [ngClass]="{'show': isExpanded}" id="fundClass" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="fundClass_heading"
        data-parent="#fundClass" [attr.aria-expanded]="isExpanded">
        <div class="card-body scrollClass" *ngIf="FundClasses && FundClasses.FundDetailsViewModel">

            <table id="FundClass" class="fundClassesTable table-striped">
                <!-- *ngIf="c != 'Buttons1'  && !CanEdit" -->
                <tr *ngFor="let c of FundClasses.FundClassColumnNames">
                    <th class="fixed-side" scope="col" [ngClass]="c != 'Buttons1'? 'tableItem bold' : 'tableItem cellbgcolor'"> {{ c }}</th>

                    <ng-container *ngFor="let fundClass of FundClasses.FundDetailsViewModel let i=index">
                        <ng-container *ngFor="let f of fundClass['FundClassDetailsViewModel'] | keyvalue">

                            <td class="tableItem" style="font-weight: bold" *ngIf="c == 'Fund Name'">
                                {{ f.value.FundName}}
                            </td>
                            <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" class="tableItem"
                                *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id] && c == 'Accounting Class Name'">{{ f.value.Description}}
                            </td>
                            <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id] && c == 'Accounting Class Name'"
                                class="tableItem">
                                <input kendoTextBox [(ngModel)]="f.value.Description"
                                    style="width: 284px; height: 29.5px;" />
                            </td>
                            <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == 'Class ID'">{{f.value.Id}}</td>
                            <td *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id] && c == 'Legal Fund Class'" class="tableItem">
                                <kendo-dropdownlist [(ngModel)]="f.value.LegalFundClassId"
                                    class="form-control  form-control-sm " [data]="fundClass.PrimaryLegalFundClasses"
                                    [filterable]="false" textField="Description" [valuePrimitive]="true"
                                    valueField="Id">
                                </kendo-dropdownlist>
                            </td>
                            <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id] && c == 'Legal Fund Class'"
                                class="tableItem">
                                {{ f.value.LegalFundClassName}}
                            </td>
                            <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id] && c == 'Inception Date'"
                                class="tableItem">
                                <kendo-datepicker [format]="'MMM dd, yyyy'" [(ngModel)]="f.value.InceptionDate"
                                    class="form-control  form-control-sm">
                                </kendo-datepicker>
                            </td>
                            <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id] && c == 'Inception Date'"
                                class="tableItem">
                                {{ f.value.InceptionDate | date:"'MMM dd, yyyy"}}
                            </td>
                            <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id] && c == 'Invested Amount'"
                                class="tableItem">
                                <input kendoTextBox [(ngModel)]="f.value.InvestedAmount"
                                    style="width: 284px; height: 29.5px;" />
                            </td>
                            <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id] && c == 'Invested Amount'"
                                class="tableItem">
                                {{ f.value.InvestedAmount | number : '.2-2'}}
                            </td>
                            <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id] && c == 'Vehicle Type'"
                                class="tableItem">
                                <kendo-dropdownlist [(ngModel)]="f.value.VehicleTypeId"
                                    class="form-control  form-control-sm " [data]="FundClasses.VehicleTypes"
                                    [filterable]="false" textField="Name" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="Id">
                                </kendo-dropdownlist>
                            </td>
                            <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id] && c == 'Vehicle Type'"
                                class="tableItem">
                                {{ f.value.VehicleTypeName}}
                            </td>
                            <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id] && c == 'Closure Status'"
                                class="tableItem">
                                <kendo-dropdownlist [(ngModel)]="f.value.ClosureStatusId"
                                    class="form-control  form-control-sm" [data]="FundClasses.ClosureStatuses"
                                    [filterable]="false" textField="Name" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="Id">
                                </kendo-dropdownlist>
                            </td>
                            <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id] && c == 'Closure Status'"
                                class="tableItem">
                                {{ f.value.ClosureStatusName}}
                            </td>
                            <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id] && c == 'Is Side Pocket?'"
                                class="tableItem">
                                <input type="checkbox" value="{{f.value.IsSidePocket}}" id="chkSidePocket"
                                    [(ngModel)]="f.value.IsSidePocket" style="width: 13px; height: 13px;" />
                                <label for="chk">Yes</label>

                            </td>
                            <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id] && c == 'Is Side Pocket?'"
                                class="tableItem">
                                {{ f.value.IsSidePocket == true ? 'Yes' : 'No'}}
                            </td>
                            <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id] && c == 'Is Thematic?'"
                                class="tableItem">
                                <input type="checkbox" value="{{f.value.IsThematic}}" style="width: 13px; height: 13px;"
                                    [(ngModel)]="f.value.IsThematic" />
                                <label for="chkThematic">Yes</label>
                            </td>
                            <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id] && c == 'Is Thematic?'"
                                class="tableItem">
                                {{ f.value.IsThematic == true ? 'Yes' : 'No'}}
                            </td>

                            <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == 'Buttons1' && CanEdit">

                                <button *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id]" type="button"
                                    class="btn btn-primary btn mr-1 "
                                    (click)="buttonClicked(f.value.Id)">Edit</button>
                                <button *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" type="button"
                                    class="btn btn-primary btn mr-1"
                                    (click)="Update(f.value.Id)">Save</button>
                                <button *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" type="button"
                                    class="btn btn-primary btn mr-1"
                                    (click)="Delete(f.value.Id)">Delete</button>
                                <button *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" type="button"
                                    class="btn btn-primary btn mr-1"
                                    (click)="buttonClicked(f.value.Id)">Cancel</button>

                            </td>

                        </ng-container>
                    </ng-container>

                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Update 1

After trying darthnach's solution, have a small issue while scrolling. I can see the contents in the margin

css

```
 th {
        padding: 7px;
        position: sticky;
        left:0;
        min-width: 300px;
        background-color:#f5f7f7;

        }
```

Screenshot 1
[image]

Screenshot 2
[image]

Here is the stackblitz

[stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d1mzew](http://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d1mzew)

Update 2

Fix for addressing the border issue while scrolling but text visibility persist while scrolling

[image]

Comment: You can simply remove the CSS statement on your `th` setting its position. If something is `fixed` it stays exactly where it is at all times.

You can read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: And you are opposed to any solution made in Javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building upon **@Sethuraman** 's answer, if you replace `padding` with `margin` and then put a border on the div wrapping table, it might solve your problem of border (not sure if this is what you're trying to address)

You can try below change:

```
.card-body {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 10px 0;
    /* border: 1px solid lightgray; */ <-- You can add or remove this based on your need
}
```

This is before and after modifying the above class.

[image]

[image]

Furthermore, you can remove the border spacing to avoid 2px scroll gap on the `th` elements while scrolling the content towards left.

```
.fundClassesTable[_ngcontent-xcq-c0] {
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Please let me know if this helps or you are looking for something else.

Comment: margin 10px 0; did add the border but i can still see some text on left margin while scrolling. Have updated the post

Comment: That maybe because you haven't set padding 0 yet. I have updated my answer by adding padding CSS in the `.card-body` class. Please try it out.

Comment: @Tom Please check the screenshots in my answer of the table before and after removing padding.

Comment: Have you uploaded the screeshot

Comment: Yes I have. Please take a look.

Comment: @Tom you haven’t awarded the bounty to anyone yet. You can split it up the bounty and award it to people who assisted you.

Comment: I have accepted your answer so doesnt the bounty get awarded to you

Comment: No, it hasn't awarded the bounty. I guess you need to do it yourself. Since this question is in grace period, you need to manually award the bounty.

Comment: @Tom Don't you think it would've been better to split the bounty? :) 
I am not sure if this option exists. But just wondering.

Comment: Its not giving me the option to split. The moment i assigned to you, it says cannot be redone

Comment: Actually, the bounty did not get assigned to me. So I was just wondering cuz one of the reasons why I spent time on this was the bounty. 

Anyway, if you can't undo this, no issues. It's completely fine.

Answer (score 2):

In `.card-body` instead of padding try margin it may solve your problem, i have wored on stackblitz -- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d1mzew

```
.card-body {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    /* padding: 10px; */
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: The stackbltiz you shared doesnt reflex the fix

Comment: I tried you css on my solution and much better than before but while scrolling i can see the table border disappearing

Comment: iam not able to save bliz and send you can try by applying the property in style.css
`.card-body {

  flex: 1 1 auto;
  margin: 10px;
}`

Comment: As I mentioned earlier I tried and it is much better than before but the border of table is disappearing while scrolling

Comment: You can try one more solution , chage the th property 'left:-10px' with 'position: sticky'
`th {
        padding: 7px;
        position: sticky;
        left:-10px;
        min-width: 300px;
        background-color:#f5f7f7;
     
        } `

Comment: left - 10px moves the header slightly to the left while scrolling

Comment: @Tom Could you please explain how the border is disappearing while scrolling? While testing on mac, I could see after replacing `padding` with `margin` the behaviour is the same.

Answer (score 2):

Try this by setting `position:sticky` and `left:-10px`.Here is the [stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gzdzkn?file=src/app/app.component.css) for the same. This will meet your requirement I guess

```
th{
    position: sticky;
    left: -10px;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code for the first column.

```css
div {
  overflow-x:scroll;  
  margin-left:6em;
  width: 300px;
    }
table th, td{
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.first-col {
  position:absolute;
 width:6em;
 left:0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ccc;
    }
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="first-col">text</th>
        <th>value</th>
        <th>value2
        </th>
        <th>value2
        </th>
        <th>value3
        </th>
        <th>value4
        </th>
        <th>value5
        </th>
        <th>value6
        </th>
        <th>value7
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="first-col">lorem ipsum</td>
        <td><strong>0</strong>
        </td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="first-col">lorem ipsum</td>
        <td><strong>0</strong>
        </td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="first-col">lorem ipsum</td>
        <td><strong>0</strong>
        </td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="first-col">lorem ipsum</td>
        <td><strong>0</strong>
        </td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="first-col">lorem ipsum</td>
        <td><strong>0</strong>
        </td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="first-col">lorem ipsum</td>
        <td><strong>0</strong>
        </td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="first-col">lorem ipsum</td>
        <td><strong>0</strong>
        </td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="first-col">lorem ipsum</td>
        <td><strong>0</strong>
        </td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: In your answer you have given fixed width. I cannot give fixed width to my table as it spans across the screen and would depend on different screen sizes. Also how do fit in the logic to my html code as I am dynamically looping through th and tds

Comment: You don't need to fit logic on HTML code you will only change the CSS code.This is the similar example and you don't need to add fixed width of the container table will take width according to data.

Comment: You are applying class to the first th and td in html. In your code th and tds are defined in advance. How is the css going to determine the first th and td in my case when it is dynamic

Comment: You ave set width: 300px; in the div element. It is shortening my table

Comment: @Tom , Mayank's answer is what you want, all you have to do is change the `.first-col {}` to be `th {}`. Simply remove the width on the div, that is only there for this example.

Comment: Hi Callum , I have updated the post with my issue. The column is now fixed but I can see data through the padding applied on the borders.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove position fixed from th and add

```
th {
  position: sticky;
  left:0;
}
```

Comment: This is very close solution but one problem. While scrolling, I can see the background contents behind the first header as i scroll.

Comment: I have fixed that issue by setting background-color:#f5f7f7; but have one small problem. I have updated the screenshot in my post

Comment: I may need to look a the code with content, but i think it can be fixed with a box containing everythin with an overflow:hidden; cause probably is because the ng-container is showing the extra content

Comment: Sorry I didn’t understand where do I put overflow:hidden

Comment: Can you make a blitz or something to preview your code?

Comment: Perfect, just change .card-body{padding:10px} to .card-body{ margin: 10px 0;}. It was making space inside the borders of the container, and you needed space outside the borders, to separate it from the other contents in your page. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-txjfnn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css